# Acumatica Override Calculate Action for ARFinChargesApplyMaint graph

Tags: overriding, action, acumatica

Have the need to override the Calculate Overdue Charges (AR507000) Calculate action.  Was going to try to override the entire CalculateFinancialCharges but that seemed to daunting (not even sure if possible).  In my extension class I just want to do some post processing:
If rows found on ARFinChargeRecords after running base Calculate logic then prompt user.  If they answer yes, iterate through ARFinChargeRecords and update FinChargeAmt with: current invoice balance * .02

I'm very new to Acumatica development and have been through all T courses.  This my first real-world problem to solve and I'm not having much luck.  It appears Base.calculate calls itself?  I tried using the example of the invoice release action override, but this seems different somehow.

Here is what I have so far in my extension class but nothing really working so far. var row1 = row is just there for breakpoint/debugging purposes:

```
    public PXAction<ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters> Calculate;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Calculate")]
    protected void calculate()
    {
        Base.calculate.Press();

        //int iCachedData = 0;
        //foreach (var row in Base.ARFinChargeRecords.Cache.Cached)
        //{
        //    iCachedData++;
        //    yield return row;
        //}

        //if (iCachedData > 0)
        //{
            if (Base.ARSetup.Ask("Apply Special Calculation (Percent Of Open Balance)", MessageButtons.YesNo) == WebDialogResult.Yes)
            {
                foreach (var row in Base.ARFinChargeRecords.Cache.Cached) {

                  var row1 = row;

                }

                // update FinChargeAmount with Balance * .02
                // Base.ARFinChargeRecords
                // Base.ARInvoices.
            }
        // }
    }
```

Comment: Scope of 'what is not working' is too broad. Try to narrow down the issue to one actionable item that is not working and describe the problem fully, ex: method override is not called.

Comment: If I run the calculate I get 2 rows showing overdue charges using the built-in logic.  I get prompted twice with the Ask (so almost like Base.calculate is recursive) but I never see any rows when I step into this.  row1 = row never gets hit.  But again, I'm not even sure if A) the calculate action can be overridden and B) if it can, I don't understand how to do it, apparently.  I'm trying to reference the labs from T300, but can't find any example that looks close to what I need to do. (run logic AFTER the base action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calculate` action can be overridden. Below is out-of-box `Calculate` action

[image: out-of-box Calculate action]

It should be overridden as below (without any of your custom logic):

```cs
public class ARFinChargesApplyMaintPXExt : PXGraphExtension<ARFinChargesApplyMaint>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual IEnumerable Calculate(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        Base.calculate.Press(adapter);

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

Out-of-box `Calculate` action starts Asynchronous operation (via `PXLongOperation.StartOperation`), creates new `Graph` instance for `ARFinChargesApplyMaint` and invokes `CalculateFinancialCharges` method (which generates rows displayed in grid)

With above observations, possible approach to address your requirement would be:

1. Add confirmation and store confirmation value (Yes/No) in hidden custom field of DAC working with Filter view (`ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters`) before invoking `Base.calculate.Press(adapter)`.
2. Override virtual method `CalculateFinancialCharges`,  and add `RowInserted` event-handler for `ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesDetails` DAC to alter logic for `FinChargeAmt` field.

Below code is for your reference

```cs
using System;
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Objects.AR;

namespace DemoPkg
{
    public class ARFinChargesApplyMaintPXExt : PXGraphExtension<ARFinChargesApplyMaint>
    {
        [PXOverride]
        public virtual IEnumerable Calculate(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            WebDialogResult result = adapter.View.Ask(Base.Filter.Current, "Confirmation",
                                                      "Apply Special Calculation (Percent Of Open Balance)?",
                                                      MessageButtons.YesNo, MessageIcon.Question);
            ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters filterData = Base.Filter.Current;
            ARFinChargesApplyParametersPXExt filterDataExt = PXCache<ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters>.GetExtension<ARFinChargesApplyParametersPXExt>(filterData);
            filterDataExt.UsrReCalcFinChargeAmt = (result == WebDialogResult.Yes);
            Base.Filter.Update(filterData);

            Base.calculate.Press(adapter);

            return adapter.Get();
        }

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual void CalculateFinancialCharges(ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters filter, Action<ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters> BaseInvoke)
        {
            ARFinChargesApplyParametersPXExt filterDataExt = PXCache<ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters>.GetExtension<ARFinChargesApplyParametersPXExt>(filter);
            if (filterDataExt.UsrReCalcFinChargeAmt.GetValueOrDefault(false))
            {
                Base.RowInserted.AddHandler<ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesDetails>((sender, e) =>
                {
                    ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesDetails data = (ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesDetails)e.Row;
                    data.FinChargeAmt = 600.00m; // your custom calculated value
                });
            }
            BaseInvoke(filter);
        }
    }

    public sealed class ARFinChargesApplyParametersPXExt : PXCacheExtension<ARFinChargesApplyMaint.ARFinChargesApplyParameters>
    {
        #region UsrReCalcFinChargeAmt
        public abstract class usrReCalcFinChargeAmt : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrReCalcFinChargeAmt> { }

        [PXDBBool]
        [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Recalc Amount", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Invisible)]
        public bool? UsrReCalcFinChargeAmt { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Below help articles can be referred in Acumatica Customization Guide

[To Override an Action Delegate Method](https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=33ec6d90-f8a1-4f57-811b-2de3fd9d1ea6)

[Altering BLC Virtual Methods](https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b2fc44a4-56a5-40ea-b9f3-23ec03765567)

Comment: Thank you for the code example and references. It's just going to take a bit for things to start clicking in my brain.  I have been doing a lot of work with XAF (DevExpress) over the past several years but took a good 1-2 years to get really comfortable with things and not fighting the framework.

Comment: I have the custom calculation working with your logic, however, I get "a dialog cannot be requested".  Tried some different overloads on the Ask method but no luck.  I wound up just setting result = WebDialogResult.Yes; to confirm the rest of the logic works.  I will try to figure out the dialog error. May have to create another post :) Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, seeing that custom boolean on the parameters makes me realize that instead of a message box I'll just add this to the parameters screen and default to true.

Comment: @rjean99, I am glad example and references were useful. You can go with either approach suitable for your need.